# Creating multiple DataFrames from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a solution to create multiple DataFrames from a dictionary that has key value pairs where the values contains DataFrames, such as:

```
dict_ = {'df1' : [dataframe],
         'df2' : [dataframe],
              ...           
         'dfi' : [dataframe]}
```

I've tried with using `.get()` as following ;

```
df1,df2,df3,df4 = dict_.get('df1'),dict_.get('df2'),dict_.get('df3'),dict_.get('df4')
```

But, It does not seem like efficient way to creating multiple DataFrames, if `dict_` contains huge sets of DataFrames.

How can I create multiple DataFrames from the dictionary, as well as, creating multiple DataFrames as df1, df2, df3, ... df*n* depending on the key values from the dictionary?

Comment: `df1, df2, df3, df4 = dict_.values()`? It seems like you have the values as a _list_ of 1 dataframe corresponding to each key in the dictionary though in the shown example.

Comment: Why would you need to create those dataframes when they are already stored neatly in a dictionary with appropriate keys. Dynamic named variables, while possible (hint: search together with `global`), are not recommended. They're buggy and hard to read later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
for name, df in dict_.items():
    globals()[name] = df
```

Alternatively, depending on the scope you need you can use locals:

```
for name,df in dict_.items():
    locals()[name] = df
```

Answer (score 1):

Not recommend but work for your situation

```
variables = locals()
for x, y in dict_.items():
    variables["{0}".format(x)] = y[0]
```